# Error when using js in href ie 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a link:

`<a href="javascript:someObject.someFunction();" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(225, 233, 41);">someText</a>`

it works fine everywhere except ie(i try ie11) i have this error

```
This page can’t be displayed. 
Make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm# is correct.
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: What does someFunction return?  Have you checked the JavaScript console in the developer tools for error messages?

Comment: You need to return false inside someFunction.

Comment: nothing, just set cookies

Comment: But you're telling your browser to load whatever it returns.  And to do it in a new window.  Does it open a new window too?

Comment: have `return false;` added after the `someFunction();`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a javascript URI scheme in a HTML href attribute, this is different to using an onclick event handler.

In IE, the result of executing that JavaScript will replace the currently loaded document.

To avoid this (without refactoring your code to not do things this way), you can end your href with the javascript operator `void`, which tells your javascript to return nothing, at all (well, *undefined*).

Then IE will stay on the current page.

`<a href="javascript:someObject.someFunction(); void 0" ...`

...and you probably don't want the `target="_blank"` since you're telling a new window to run your JavaScript code, and your function is not available in that window.

Comment: If it works everywhere except IE 11, then your `someFunction()` function is probably returning undefined anyway, since this is the default return value for functions that do not have a return statement.

Comment: @Suhan, remove `target="_blank"`, see what happens.

Comment: I had that same behavior in FireFox (34.0.5) and IE11(11.0.12), your "void 0" solution worked fine for both, in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would do this instead:

```
<a href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); someObject.someFunction();" target="_blank" style="color: rgb(225, 233, 41);">someText</a>
```

It will open a new tab as you intended, and it works in chrome, firefox and IE.