# Error when I click on href link with internet explorer 11

Tags: javascript

I have already checked this link [Error when using js in href ie 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077303/error-when-using-js-in-href-ie-11) but it does not resolve my problem.

My link is located on an application A and when I click on my link, I send an information to an application B:
Here is my link located on Application A:

```
<a target="_blank" href="javascript:displayInfinityPage({{userName}});">{{l10n "Data access"}}&nbsp;</a>
```

Here is my JavaScript function:

```
//Posts the username back to Application B
function displayInfinityPage(username){
    window.opener.postMessage(username,"*");
}
```

This is how I receive data on Application B:

```
function onMessageApp(e) {
    if (e.data != "1") {
    var consumerPageSearchOpened = ((document.getElementById('DEBTOR_ID')) ? true:false);
    if (e.origin == "http://10.1.92.3:9090" && consumerPageSearchOpened) {
    document.getElementById("ID").value = e.data;
    document.getElementByName("subcommand").click();
    } else {
    alert("Application B is rejecting message from  "+e.origin+");
    }
    } else if (e.data == 1) {
    alert("Update status");
    command=collections.changeicstatus&i3_status=0
    var url = document.getElementById("curSession").value+'?command=collections.changeicstatus&i3_status=0';
    command=collections.changeicstatus&i3_status=0';
    window.location = url;
    window.opener.location.href = url;
        }
}

window.addEventListener("message",onMessageApp,true);
```

This is the error I get:

this page can't be displayed make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm# is correct

And Application A is opening a new tab with "javascript:displayInfinityPage({{147852}});" appears in the address bar instead of populating 147852 in Application B ("ID" field)

Comment: You don't need `+"` at the end of `alert("Application B is rejecting message from  "+e.origin+");`

Comment: Please post the error you are getting and any javascript libraries you are using (where is squiggly bracket syntax in `{{userName}}` coming from?)

Comment: Does removing `target="_blank"` help?

Comment: Also please provide some information on your setup; that doesn't look like pure HTML.

Comment: target="_blank" does not help.

Comment: Do you still get the same error after removing `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Also, do you get any errors in the console? Open the console with `F12`, then click anchor, and see if anything is logged in the console.

Comment: Yes I do. But I also need target="_blank" because on clicking on the link I need to send data to another page located to another application

Comment: Can you paste those errors? `target="_blank"` is only necessary when _opening_ a new page; you'll still be able to send information to another application.

Comment: This is the error I have: This page can’t be displayed

•Make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm# is correct.
•Look for the page with your search engine.
•Refresh the page in a few minutes.

Comment: I opened the console with F12 but I have found no error in the console

Comment: Can someone help me please?

Comment: The application A is developed in Java and the application B is developed in php. Please help. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I have The same problem. 
The error is: This page can’t be displayed. 
Make sure the web address //ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm# is correct.