# Bookmarklet in MS-Edge IE-Mode

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Please tell me how to run bookmarklet in MS-Edge IE-Mode.

In IE, I have built bookmarklet to open local folders and files by ActiveXObject, corresponding to shown web page.
But in MS-Edge I got Error Message,".. //ieframe.dll/dnserror.htm?ErrorStatus=0x80070005# .." to click this bookmarklet set in favorite toolbar.
I can't find how to get over this error.
please tell me.

Comment: I have tested bookmarklets in IE mode, and found that bookmarklets just don't work in IE mode. Unfortunately, there seems to be no solution yet. But I have found [a similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077303/error-when-using-js-in-href-ie-11). You may get inspired by it. The solution provided by Lee Kowalkowski may be of help to you. If it does not work, I would suggest sending a feedback to Edge Team by pressing **Alt+Shift+I**.

Comment: Thank you, Yu Zhou! But To try the "void 0" solution you have found, I get the same Error Message. So, I should give up finding the solution by simple bookmarklet  and approach by using WebDriver.